# Load a new page when an HTML link is clicked

Tags: php, html, authentication

i am working on a login form and i basically want the user to be able to get redirected on the singup form when he clicks to a link. Any help?

Comment: Any effort you want to share with us? Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Answer (score 0):

Can be done simply with **HTML** `href` tag like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/sign_up_form_url">Sign Up</a>
```

If you want to add via **php**:

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com/sign_up_form_url">Sign Up</a>';
```

[**Read More**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) about `href`

Answer (score 0):

Create an anchor with an `href` attribute with a link to your `signup page` as follows

```
<a href="http://link_to_form_page">sign up</a>
```